# How can I store a non-string object in data memory?

Tags: android, storage, gesture

In particular, I want to store a given gesture in the device's memory. Usually for these things I use SharedPreferences, but since gesture isn't a primitive data type, that doesn't work here; I also looked into storing it on Internal Storage, which is what I want, but the code here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html suggests this only works for strings.

Is there a way to easily store objects in the device memory, or do I need to convert the object to a string then back convert when I read the file?

```
Gesture mGesture;
SharedPreferences stored = getSharedPreferences("Shared Preferences", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = stored.edit();
byte[] storedGesture = serializeObject(mGesture);
String storedGestureString = new String(storedGesture);
editor.putString("Gesture Password", storedGestureString);
}

public static byte[] serializeObject(Object mObject){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try{
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(mObject);
        out.close();

        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
        return buf;

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("serialize object", "error", ioe);
        return null;
    }
}
```

There's the relevant code to my attempt at serializing, the app crashes when I hit the Confirm button after creating the gesture. The Confirm button runs this code, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can serialize the object and back. That way you'll be able to use it both with `SharedPreferences` and Internal Storage.

Here is a tutorial on how to implement Serialization in Java (as well as Android) - 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: Hmm this is pretty good, but my app is crashing when I run the line that converts the byte array to a String. In particular I have: String string = new String(byte_array); So I guess that last part is all I'm having trouble with?

Comment: Well, I think you don't really need to convert the `byte` array to `String`, because the `byte` `Array` object itself can be serialized. Also I don't see the lines `String string = new String(byte_array);` in the code you posted at the question.

Comment: Yeah, it seemed like an unnecessary step, but the problem I'm coming across is how can I store a byte array in something like a SharedPreference? Don't I need it to be a string?

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought it'd be easier to save them in internal / external storage. I doubt `SharedPreferences` have been designed to cater such data.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Java's Serializable interface. You can make your own object that implements Serializable to hole the gesture, then write that object to internal storage. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) is a link for using serialization in Android.